An apocalypse leads remnants of humanity to spread out. Would a "peaceful military force" be a likely force for rebuilding a nation and its economy?
So, there are plenty of questions that handle rebuilding, but I'm concerned with one possibility. As you'll probably notice, a lot of the world outside of this faction is inspired by the early wild west.
Here's the scenario I have:
Some faction has a near-infinite supply of military technology. They have some automated system that's been pumping out military trucks and helicopters in huge quantities. It's not infinite, and they can't afford to just give things away willy-nilly, but they can provide transportation, and of course, security, to the people of the post-collapse world. Because of their goal of banding the people of the "wasteland" together, my placeholder name for them is the Union.
Following the collapse, while there are of course bandits, there's no one big-bad faction, no zombies roaming the wastes, nor are there any governments. The largest "cities" have 300-800 people, while most settlements are under 40. Warring tribes of course exist, but they're the exception. While the faction does wish to quash the wars (either by brokering peace or simply picking a side and using their hardware and manpower to eliminate the other), it's only one of the small benefits they wish to provide.
The key point here is that, while dangerous, it's not a hellhole. Many people spend the winter bundled up in log cabins, but they're not dying left and right, disease hasn't ravaged the land, and again, there is no one, objective "enemy" to fight off. Life is hard, but it's the kind of hard that tough people can rise to, not the kind that forces you to live like rats.
See, while most post-apocalypse factions in fiction that focus on growing are actively imperialistic, this faction wants a democracy or republic to get all of the people of these settlements working together. They have a bit of saviour complex and are actively seeking to "tame the frontier", but they also don't intend to become authoritarian.
To do this, they offer a number of services:

As mentioned, they help maintain peace, partially through maintaining an actual military.
1.B. "Celebrity units", highly specialized, and similarly revered, units are used to show off the effectiveness of their military.
They form a transport network that allows them to move food and other goods easily.
2.B. They build a trade network on the back of this transport network, establishing their own economy and setting up trading posts in major settlements.
2.C. They form a currency to support this. They pay people with this currency, but also sell the occasional equipment (cars, radios, and whatnot) back to them with the same currency.
They "secure" large areas with patrols, or even massive fences, allowing farmers to spread out and take as much land as they like.
Their military equipment includes military ambulances (like those ambulance humvees, or even medevac helicopters), they use these to turn local healthcare options (a doctor's dining room table) into centralized infirmaries/hospitals where people can be brought.
While they can't give away their equipment as much as they want, a small amount of it is demilitarized and used for farming purposes (tractors and crop dusters)

The idea is that many of these measures are less useful for their base value and more useful for how they convince people that they're a force for good. "Union dollars" give people a sense of the normal "world before" and the valiant "Union rangers" not only show people that a military force can be trusted, but help convince idealistic young men to join the cause.
There will be outsiders, but what concerns me as to how practical is ensuring that all of this would make the outsiders be the minority.
Many people will want to remain alone, but this group needs manpower. How do they recruit when most people will see their military trucks and go "I'm not working with those fascists". Again, this is not a totalitarian group.
All of these advancements require two things: One, a high level of trust, Two, manpower. Outside of transportation and weaponry, the rest, like the currency, would come merely from the fact that something they were able to provide earlier got them established as a legitimate government.
Their currency also brings me to an issue. They can do one of two things: Federalize the trade networks by owning the farms or just making sure that the farmers sell primarily to them, then sell this food back to the people at rates which make them pull in money. This ensures that the amount of money in the economy is controllable. Selling demilitarized equipment to the people, as well as constantly creating more efficiency in the system, increases the material value of the goods in circulation, making the population as a whole "better off", while still having the same actual number of dollars minted. Or, they allow for totally free trade. Again, they can't give out as much as they want, so the amount of things that they can sell to the population is of lower value than the manpower they get. This has two dangerous routes: One. the government must continually mint more money to pay people while not being able to back that money up with some value, and inflation occurs, or Two, no new money is printed and no inflation occurs because the vehicles, radios, and whatever else that they sell to the population (they're the only source) are extremely expensive, and they make a good bit of money back. The economy would shift from individual small business to a handful of larger business starting, as the average individual wouldn't always be able to source the extremely expensive goods required to start up the kinds of business that require physical equipment. Additionally, these things wouldn't be able to help the average day-to-day life. This is another thing that I was wondering and hoping someone could help me out on. I don't know enough about real-world financial history, especially in cases of new colonies or new governments.
Would the start of any of these actually be enough to convince people to put their lives and livelihoods on the line to trust that these newcomers in their scary military helicopters with their scary military fatigues can actually be trusted? Historically, are frontiersmen ever willing to trade the freedom that comes with untamed land for the safety that comes with a government overhead? Is it at all practical to achieve any of these things?

Sorry, but you are asking us to advise what the decisions of the characters in your story should be, ie write your story.  That is not what this site is for - we can look at possible consequences of an incentive scheme that you describe, but you need to write the story.

As a side note - you use the term Fascist - but nothing in your story is remotely Fascistic. I think you mean Authoritarian. They are not the same thing and although not the purview of World Building per se - one should educate oneself on what words and philosophies mean.

In addition to @KerrAvon2055's comment: (a) We do not help people write stories (see [help/on-topic]). (b) Brainstorming is discouraged (see [help/on-topic]) and questions that are open-ended or lead to all answers having equal value are prohibited (see [help/dont-ask]). Worldbuilding is independent of all stories because it's the structure upon which stories unfold. You need to make your story decisions (storybuilding). We can then help you rationalize those decisions (worldbuilding). Sometime after about rep 500 we'll start holding you responsible for the rules in the [tour] and [help].

@KerrAvon2055
I wasn't trying to ask for storybuilding help, I think I worded this poorly.
It was not intended to be "What does main character john smith do in this situation?", but "what would this government look like?" or "what kind of government would naturally be formed in this scenario?" If that's still too close to storybuilding, then I'll delete this.

@JBH
In addition to what I just commented for KerrAvon, (I was going to tag you both, but apparently I can only tag one person), I'll edit my post to try add in the thoughts I had on what the government would look like, and ask how practical this is.
If I'm not mistaken, that should be on the level?

@Walt no type of government forms "naturally" or there would only be one type of government. Read the history of the formation of any government and you will find it is a battle of wills, cunning, ruthlessness and charisma between determined individuals with their own agendas. Eg the government of a Trotsky-led USSR would have been very different to the Stalin-based one that happened. The "story" is not the decisions of 1 or 2 characters, it is the product of the decisions of all characters, including who gets to lead the government, what they choose to do and how people react.

@KerrAvon2055 I understand that, but deceit and backstabbing isn't currently my concern. Whatever happens internally for this group, whoever gets betrayed and stabbed, the end result is what I wrote in my revision of the post. I'm just asking whether or not that end result is actually at all logical. I don't want to write a story about what goes into forming a government if the whole premise and motivation of the government makes no sense. I'm also asking for help from someone with a better understanding of how economies are built in dire situations.

The military force in your scenario is essentially its own nation and economy, so they are guaranteed to eventually win, as long as they secure the one resource they likely are lacking: women. As long as they can convince enough fertile women to join them (and lets be honest, they have fantastic advantage with their tech and security) they will outbreed and outlive any other faction within 1-2 generations.

The problem will solve itself. If your protagonists have the technology to produce an effectively infinite supply of advanced aircraft, vehicles, weapons and other advanced military equipment (and presumably access to an 'infinite' supply of raw materials/inputs that by default must also has to be available? Then they can set themselves up as a manufacturing hub for every other town they can reach (which by default would be all of them).
Firstly if you can produce modern aircraft and trucks you must also be able to produce spare parts for the same. And all those other towns will desperately need spare parts as the years progress. So you trade your way to establishing a degree of control by setting up a series of rules that require all participants to 'play nice' if they want to be part of your trade network. One key rule? No trading the stuff we give you with anyone who hasn't signed up as a member of the trade network without getting our permission first (or your out!).
On top of that your protagonists must also have a high degree of control over what they can produce. By this I mean the system produces the piece of equipment someone wants on demand. ( I.E. it's not the case that your system just cycles through a long list of stuff its been told to produce from day one with everyone then having to wait until the parts or machine they want finally comes back to the top of the list again.)
And since components from most advanced military systems can also be used in civilian equipment (e.g. electric motors, simple sheet steel, circuit boards etc... this implies your town has the ability to eventually start producing household goods as well, anything from light bulbs, to washing machines, to mobile phones etc. You name it. You then alternate between production runs  military vs civilian as needed.
If you can produce a strong enough military to protect your town/facility  from assault and guard deliveries to and from other towns for as long as they need guarding? Your best strategy is trade, especially if you offer reasonably fair terms.  You won't have to threaten the vast majority of townships with military force, they will buy into the new 'system' voluntarily because you are literally helping them keep the lights on. Your only problem will be the inevitable holdouts and there you only need to act aggressively if they do. So you keep an eye on them but otherwise do nothing. Then watch as they wither away from a lack of modern tech.
EDIT: But what do the other towns have to trade in return you ask? Apart from things like food and agricultural products? One word, LABOR, Most of the small towns would willingly offer a couple of strong backs for whatever duties were needed in exchange for a steady supply of goods - just so long as the volunteers are treated well and allowed to cycle back home at regular intervals if they want to. A lot, probably most of them won't want to given the better living conditions in your larger town. In fact over time all your small communities will tend to congregate into a few larger ones as long as you can provide the transport and building materials for new homes etc that would make such a move possible. And most of the communities closest to your facility will probably opt to move nearby for security and ease of access to supplies anyway. With luck your military efforts will mostly be in the form of security/policing duties and bandit control, not the forced annexations of towns at gun point.

This is much how the Cold War was won, those allied together against communists would trade basic household appliances and such to gain allies and then later trade in weapons to establish new areas of defense.  Someone able to make good tanks could make good tractors for agriculture.  To be able to make secure communication radios means being able to make good broadcast radios for news and entertainment.  To make good computers for artillery means being able to make good computers for accounting and video games.  Being able to make good cameras for weddings means making good scopes for rifles.
